# VGG16 model always predicts the first class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I saw [this tutorial](https://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/08/bottleneck-features-multi-class-classification-keras.html) on how to do multi-class classification with the VGG16 model using bottleneck-features. The last section of the article is talking about how to make predictions with the trained model, and I'm trying to transform that part into real-time predictions. But my code always predicts the first class...

```
face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/hui-hungchen/Desktop/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read()  # captures frame and returns boolean value and captured image
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces_detected = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_img, 1.32, 5)
faces_list = []
for (x, y, w, h) in faces_detected:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), thickness=7)
    face_frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    face_frame = cv2.cvtColor(face_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    face_frame = cv2.resize(face_frame, (224, 224))
    face_frame = img_to_array(face_frame)
    face_frame = np.expand_dims(face_frame, axis=0)
    face_frame = face_frame/255
    face_frame = preprocess_input(face_frame)
    faces_list.append(face_frame)

    # build the VGG16 network
    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    #for layer in model.layers:
        #print(layer, layer.trainable)

    # get the bottleneck prediction from the pre-trained VGG16 model
    bottleneck_prediction = model.predict(faces_list)

    # build top model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=bottleneck_prediction.shape[1:]))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    model.load_weights('/Users/hui-hungchen/Desktop/Science_Fair_Project/Main/EmotionDetectionModel.h5')
    # use the bottleneck prediction on the top model to get the final classification
    class_predicted = model.predict_classes(bottleneck_prediction)

    # find max indexed array
    max_index = np.argmax(class_predicted[0])

    members = ("Member 1","Member 2")
    predicted_members = members[max_index]
    print (predicted_members)
```

It always predicts Member 1, and if I change the order of Member 1 and Member 2, it just changes the predictions from Member 1 to Member 2.

I have achieved a validation accuracy of 98% when training my model so I don't think this part is the problem, but I'm not sure.